# Securing api to api connection in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I have 2 resource in azure
- azure functions app service that will call "feedback api"
- .net core web app service that has a feedback api controller which should be only available for the function app

I would like to setup `[Authorize]` attribute in the controller in the way that only azure function will be able to authorise (for example with some generated key).

Is there any out of the box solution for this, and if not how can I add it?

Comment: I have few questions around your scenario like if you want to Authorize only particular controller or complete app service? In the later case Azure AD provide out of box solution where you can register your both Apps with Azure AD and create a trust between them without getting into code and it will work.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad

Comment: I would like to secure only one controller. Other controllers use standard AD user credentials. This one is use from function app.

Comment: You can check for shared secured key in web api controller that is sent from function app through headers or query string. If you want better than that i would suggest azure key vault. Create key in azure key vault that azure function can read and send to web api controller.  web api can cross verify the key from azure key vault. For better security You can put key on rotation.